# Github vs npm markdown, escaping vertical bar

Tags: node.js, npm, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

For a table cell in Github markdown, you have to escape `|` with `\` to avoid having it interpreted as the next cell. Once you escape it, everything is fine e.g. https://github.com/russellw/clause-normal-form the entries for Nor and Or.

For a table cell in npm markdown, this doesn't work; the `\` comes out in the display e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/clause-normal-form the entries for Nor and Or.

How to escape `|` in a table in a readme, such that Github and npm will both display it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `<code>&vert; &verbar; &VerticalLine; &#x0007C; &#124;</code>`

The above is rendered as: `| | | | |`

You should be able to use HTML entities in Markdown and `<code></code>` instead of backticks will avoid auto-escaping of `&` as `&amp;` inside. Of course you may have some other characters that need escaping depending on your particular example.

For more entities see: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Remember that you can use HTML (including HTML entities) in Markdown:

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.

See: https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html

Comment: Ah! That does work in plain text, thanks. The remaining problem is that in this case the vertical bars are the names of operators, so should be formatted in code font, which is normally done by putting things between backticks, but that breaks the HTML entities in this case. Is there a way to get them to render in code font?

Comment: @rwallace You can try using `<code>ABC</code>` instead of backticks.